# I can't figure out what keeps crashing in routing

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

### Error:[image: Error]

So this error keeps popping up up locally, but not on the hosted version (https://chez-mout.web.app/home/index)

I've just done what I learned this year at school, create a routing module, and pass along each submodule to handle it's own routing. Guess I made a mistake somewhere but I just can't seem to find it. Here's some code:

### Routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule' },
 { path: 'recipes', loadChildren: './recipe/recipe.module#RecipeModule' },
 {
   path: 'reservation',
   loadChildren: './reservation/reservation.module#ReservationModule'
 },
 {
   path: 'review',
   loadChildren: './review/review.module#ReviewModule'
 },
 { path: '', redirectTo: 'home/index', pathMatch: 'full' },
 { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
@NgModule({
 imports: [
   RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
     preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
   }),
   CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

### HomeModule

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
 {
   path: "index",
   component: HomeComponent
 }
];

@NgModule({
 declarations: [HomeComponent],
 imports: [
   CommonModule,
   MDBModule,
   RouterModule.forChild(appRoutes),
   ParallaxDirective
 ]
})
export class HomeModule {}
```

My other modules look exactly the same, if you need them though, I'll post them

Comment: Why are you very sure it is routing? I can't see anything in the error complaint about routing.

Comment: because @AbdelrhmanHussien, the error occured when I added my routing to my project and it won't display my `<router-outlet>`